Facing issues with UTM parameters in GA4
We are facing issues with GA4 analytics. We are running multiple banner ads on various websites, so to track them we are using UTM parameters, but GA4 is not not tracking any of these parameters.
This is how we are using UTM parameters: https://www.example.com/upsc-master-class/?utm_source=direct&utm_medium=ExpressIndian&utm_campaign=BannerAds
It should show ExpressIndian in session medium but currently I haven't seen a single session with ExpressIndian parameter in GA4. Attaching screenshot of last 10 days of traffic.
Screenshot:

We have tried everything to solve this issue. Can anyone help us solve or understand where we are going wrong?

You're using the parameters incorrectly.

utm_source is the identifier for the site/source the traffic is coming from.  I assume this value should be ExpressIndian in your case
utm_medium is the type of source, eg ppc,referral,social etc
utm_campaign is the name of your specific campaign.  Yours is fine, but it may be a bit too general if it is not intended to be a permanent campaign.

"Direct" tends to be used to mean there is no referrer information available.
Beyond that, is traffic from the sites you are running ads on showing elsewhere?  It may just be that no one is clicking.  People can be pretty blind to banner ads, and just having them does not mean anyone will come.

Oh ! We will change that to see if it works. And people are clicking ads as the overall traffic and conversion has increased, its just we are not able to track traffic and clicks.
